# Kafka mirror skipping some topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafkaMirror between two datacenters. I have used kafka with topics A and B, they are working ok on each datacenter separately, but when using kafkaMirror the weird thing is that just one of the topics gets replicated.

My config:
--num.streams=4
--whitelist=A|B

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mirror both topics you can use `--whitelist="A,B"`

Comment: I am using that configuration, but it's not working, just topic A is picked up